# Creating text files not working

Tags: vb.net, file

This is probably a question that many of you have already seen a couple of times, but I'm really desperate since every solution i find on the internet doesn't work properly.

I want to create a simple .txt file. My code atm:

```
Public Class Form3
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Your world needs a name")
        Else
            Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
            file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\test.txt", True)
            file.WriteLine("Here is the first string.")
            file.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

So as you can see, a file should be created when the button is pressed AND when there is text in the textbox.

Is the program not working or am searching the file in the wrong place? Thanks in avance!

Comment: Not a good idea to create a file in the root directory of your (probably) system drive. However, not working is too generic, what is the real error messsage? By the way, if you need to write only few lines better use File.WriteAllLines/WriteAllText with a single line

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem is: i don't get an error when the path is just C:\! I tried it with a path to My Documents but it gives an exception, see this link for an image: https://gyazo.com/48822b173e42c14e83db3ea461c2b646

Comment: Uhm in the attempt on the My Documents you don't have added the name of the file. I can't read the details of your exception but this seems pretty clear a reference to a missing file or something

Comment: It worked! I'm sorry, i'm quit a noob with Visual Basic.net and the code in my learning book didn't work at all. Thank you very much! Can i give you an upvote now or something? :p

Comment: Thanks, but don't worry about it. There is already an answer that is more or less your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may also be used:

```
Public Class Form3
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Your world needs a name")
        Else
            Using file As New StreamWriter("c:\test.txt", True)
                file.WriteLine("Here is the first string.")
                file.Close()
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
Public Class Form3
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Your world needs a name")
    Else
        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "test.txt"), True)
        file.WriteLine("Here is the first string.")
        file.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```